# Query against a database with a combination of OR conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to perform a query against a database with a combination of OR conditions.
By filling out the form with corresponding fields in the database, after receiving the data, I put the query in such a way:

```
if ($state != '') {
    $xstate = " `State` LIKE '%" . $state . "%' ";
    $Isall = '0';
} else {
    $xstate=" `State` LIKE '-' ";
}

if ($dateStart != '' && $dateEnd != '') {
    $xdateStart = " `datefill`  BETWEEN '" . $dateEnd . "' AND '" . $dateStart . "'";
    echo $xdateStart;
    $Isall = '0';
}
```

as you can see, I check if the field is empty or not then I start to build the query, after asking all the relevant questions the query will look like:

```
$query="SELECT " .$field  . "  FROM  issueslog WHERE  ".$xdateStart." OR " .$xCode   ."   ;
```

and so on, my problem now is when I fill some field, for example xCode now is with data let say "900" and dateStart as you can see above is
      `$xdateStart=" datefill  BETWEEN '".$dateEnd."' AND '".$dateStart."'";`

so what I`m understood is that it will fetch data that corresponde to the code "900" between the specific dates, but what I get is result that coressponde only the the xCode 900, its seems that the date was abandoned.

I'd like to get suggestions, Thanks in advance.

EDIT
My generated query is:

```
SELECT *  FROM  issueslog WHERE   `datefill`  BETWEEN '2013-05-24' AND '2013-05-24' OR  `xCode` LIKE '-'  OR  `Address` LIKE '-'  OR  `tname` = '-'  OR  `fname` LIKE '-'  OR  `Phone1` LIKE '-'  OR  `State` LIKE '-'  OR  `City` LIKE '%TelAviv%'
```

Comment: Looks like you want AND not OR

Comment: If it would be AND then the query is not a general feel and I'll ask a question about each field inserted and by this to the query, it is not over.

Comment: @OfirAttia - could you add your generated query to the question? You might want to wrap each criterion in brackets, to make sure that the precedence is correct, too, as AND has a higher precedence than OR

Comment: @andrewsi Sure, you can see now the generated query.

Comment: It may be the order of which is run. You may want to play around with this line: $query="SELECT " .$field  . "  FROM  issueslog WHERE  (".$xdateStart.") OR " .$xCode   ."   ; Notice the parenthesis placements. Try to move them around to where it makes sense to you.

Comment: @StaticVoid I tried to do that and there is no result.

Comment: In light of your update, it should most likely be: $query="SELECT " .$field  . "  FROM  issueslog WHERE  (".$xdateStart.") OR (" .$xCode   .")"   ; Try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the code line:

```
$query="SELECT " .$field  . "  FROM  issueslog WHERE  ".$xdateStart." OR " .$xCode   ."
```

and then you say "so what I`m understood is that it will fetch data that corresponde to the code "900" between the specific dates".

It is simple.  Your understanding is wrong.  That code will fetch all rows that match the date condition regardless of xCode *plus* all rows that match the xCode condition regardless of date.  If you want both at once, then you need `and`:

```
$query="SELECT " .$field  . "  FROM  issueslog WHERE  ".$xdateStart." AND " .$xCode   ."
```

Your final query is

```
SELECT *
FROM  issueslog
WHERE   `datefill`  BETWEEN '2013-05-24' AND '2013-05-24' OR  `xCode` LIKE '-'  OR  `Address` LIKE '-'  OR  `tname` = '-'  OR  `fname` LIKE '-'  OR  `Phone1` LIKE '-'  OR  `State` LIKE '-'  OR  `City` LIKE '%TelAviv%'
```

I think what you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM  issueslog
WHERE  ( `datefill`  BETWEEN '2013-05-24' AND '2013-05-24') AND
       (`xCode` LIKE '-'  OR  `Address` LIKE '-'  OR  `tname` = '-'  OR  `fname` LIKE '-'  OR  `Phone1` LIKE '-'  OR  `State` LIKE '-'  OR  `City` LIKE '%TelAviv%')
```

My guess is that if any reasonable user puts a date range on rows from a table, that user will want *only* rows from that date range.  Maybe the other conditions can be connected by `OR`.  Maybe they should be connected by `AND`.  Maybe the user should actually have the option to specify how to connect those conditions.

Comment: I did it and there is no result, its just give all the data from the table without any filtering

Comment: @OfirAttia . . . The last query with the *AND* between the clauses puts a filter on `datefill`.  You should not get all rows in the table, unless all have the same date.